# What does CBATTError Code insufficientResources really mean?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to send data over BLE from my iPhone to an ESP32 board. I'm developing in flutter platform and I'm using [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble) library.

My iPhone can connect to the other device and it can also send 1 byte using `writeCharacterisiticWithResponse` function. But when I try to send my real data which is large (>7000 bytes), it then gives me the error:

```
flutter: Error occured when writing 9f714672-888c-4450-845f-602c1331cdeb : 
Exception: GenericFailure<WriteCharacteristicFailure>(
code: WriteCharacteristicFailure.unknown,
message: "Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=17 
"Resources are insufficient." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Resources are insufficient.}")
```

I tried searching for this error but didn't find additional info, even in [Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbatterror/code/insufficientresources). It just says:

> Resources are insufficient to complete the ATT request.

What does this error really means? Which resources are not sufficient and how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a characteristic value cannot be larger than 512 bytes. This is set by the ATT standard (Bluetooth Core Specification v5.3, Vol 3, Part F (ATT), section 3.2.9). This number has been set arbitrarily by the protocol designers and does not map to any technical limitation of the protocol.

So, don't send 7000 bytes in a single write. You need to keep it at most 512 to be standard compliant.

If you say that it works with another Bluetooth stack running on the GATT server, then I guess CoreBluetooth does not enforce/check the maximum length of 512 bytes on the client side (I haven't tested). Therefore I also guess the error code you see was sent by the remote device rather than by CoreBluetooth locally as a pre-check.

There are three different common ways of writing a characteristic on the protocol level (Bluetooth Core Specification v5.3, Vol 3, Part G (GATT), section 4.9 Characteristic Value Write):

1. Write Without Response (4.9.1)
2. Write Characteristic Value (4.9.3)
3. Write Long Characteristic Values (4.9.4)

Number one is unidirectional and does not result in a response packet. It uses a single ATT_WRITE_CMD packet where the value must be at most ATT_MTU-3 bytes in length. This length can be retrieved using [`maximumWriteValueLength(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1620312-maximumwritevaluelength#) with `.withoutResponse`. The `requestMtu` method in  flutter_reactive_ble uses this method internally. If you execute many writes of this type rapidly, be sure to add flow control to avoid CoreBluetooth dropping outgoing packets before they are sent. This can be done through [`peripheralIsReadyToSendWriteWithoutResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/2874034-peripheralisreadytosendwritewith) by simply always waiting for this callback after each write, before you write the next packet. Unfortunately, it seems flutter_reactive_ble does not implement this flow control mechanism.

Number two uses a single ATT_WRITE_REQ where the value must be at most ATT_MTU-3 bytes in length, just as above. Use the same approach as above to retrieve that maximum length (note that `maximumWriteValueLength` with `.withResponse` always returns 512 and is not what you want). Here however, either an ATT_WRITE_RSP will be returned on success or an error packet will be received with an error code. Only one ATT transaction can be outstanding at a time, which significantly lowers throughput compared to Write Without Response.

Number three uses a sequence of multiple ATT_PREPARE_WRITE_REQ packets (containing offset and value) followed by an ATT_EXECUTE_WRITE_REQ. The maximum length of the value in each each chunk is ATT_MTU-5. Each _REQ packet also requires a corresponding _RSP packet before it can continue (alternatively, an error code could be sent by the remote device). This approach is used when the characteristic value to be written is too long to be sent using a single ATT_WRITE_REQ.

For any of the above write methods, you are always also limited by the maximum attribute size of 512 bytes as per the specification.

Any Bluetooth stack I know of transparently chooses between "Write Characteristic Value" and "Write Long Characteristic Values" when you tell it to write with response, depending on the value length and MTU. Server side it's a bit different. Some stacks put the burden on the user to combine all packets but it seems nimble handles that on its own. From what I can see in the source code (https://github.com/apache/mynewt-nimble/blob/26ccb8af1f3ea6ad81d5d7cbb762747c6e06a24b/nimble/host/src/ble_att_svr.c#L2099) it can return the "Insufficient Resources" error code when it tries to allocate memory but fails (most likely due to too much buffered data). This is what might happen for you. To answer your first actual question, the standard itself does not say anything else about this error code than simply "Insufficient Resources to complete the request".

The error has nothing to do with LE Data Length extension, which is simply an optimization for a lower layer (BLE Link Layer) that does not affect the functionality of the host stack. The L2CAP layer will take care of the reassembling of smaller link layer packets if necessary, and must always support up to the negotiated MTU without overflowing any buffers.

Now, to answer your second question, if you send very large amounts of data (7000 bytes), you must divide the data in multiple chunks and come up with a way to correctly be able to combine them. Each chunk is written as a full characteristic value. When you do this, be sure to send values at most of size ATT_MTU-3 (but never larger than 512 bytes), to avoid the inefficient overheads of "Write Long Characteristic Values". It's then up to your application code to make sure you don't run out of memory in case too much data is sent.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly larger than this characteristic's maximum value length (which is probably on the order of 10s of bytes, not 1000s of bytes). Before writing, you need to call [`maximumWriteValueLength(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1620312-maximumwritevaluelength#) to see how much data can be written. If you're trying to send serial data over a characteristic (which is common, but not really what they were designed for), you'll need to break your data up into chunks and reassemble them on the peripheral. You will likely either need an "end" indicator of some kind, or you will need to send the length of the payload first so that the receiver knows how much to excpect.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your answer. I used the same Flutter App to send the same large data to an Arduino device that run `Arduino-BLE` library. It worked back then. Then I started using another BLE library on Arduino `nimBLE`. Since then it doesn't work anymore. In the light of your answer I assume that `Arduino-BLE` library handles the receiving of multiple consecutive packets until the whole data arrives but the `nimBLE` doesn't handle this internally. I have to handle this myself so that it works again. Can it be correct?

Comment: I don't think it's the library. I expect it's because an Arduino is probably using an nRF52840, which is a pretty awesome chip and supports Bluetooth 5.2, which can shovel data to and from an iPhone very quickly (up to 2 Mbps). The ESP32 is nice; I like it. But it's has a little tiny Bluetooth stack that only supports 4.2. It does support DLE, but I'm not sure nimble does (https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=26698). Without DLE, you're looking at payloads of ~27 bytes per message, which is very slow and will definitely overflow buffers if you try to send that much data all at once.

Comment: (to be clear, BLE can chunk data at the protocol level, but the buffers are only so large, and the error you're seeing is saying you've overflowed them, so you need to provide chunking at the application level. The method I mentioned is how you ask iOS what size it can handle per write from you.)

Comment: I also recommend https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/ to get a deeper understanding of what iOS supports.